# What is the updated syntax for RicianChannel?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB R2014a the following two files of code worked:

```
chan = RicianChannel(1/bitrate,100,8);
chan = comm.RicianChannel(1/bitrate,100,8);
```

However, in R2021a they no longer do. What is the updated syntax for this?

Comment: I suggest starting by reading the [documentation page on `ricianChannel`](https://mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.ricianchannel-system-object.html). If you want to see the differences in syntax, either log on to the MathWorks' site to view documentation from previous versions, or call `doc RicianChannel` or `doc comm.RicianChannel` in both MATLAB versions itself.

Comment: “No longer works”. Do you get the wrong output? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the error? It is hard to help you if you tell us so little. See [ask].

Answer (score -1):

````
ricianchan = comm.RicianChannel( ...
    'SampleRate',1e6, ...
    'PathDelays',[0.0 0.5 1.2]*1e-6, ...
    'AveragePathGains',[0.1 0.5 0.2], ...
    'KFactor',2.8, ...
    'DirectPathDopplerShift',5.0, ...
    'DirectPathInitialPhase',0.5, ...
    'MaximumDopplerShift',50, ...
    'DopplerSpectrum',doppler('Bell', 8), ...
    'RandomStream','mt19937ar with seed', ...
    'Seed',73, ...
    'PathGainsOutputPort',true);```
````

Comment: in my code what value is 100 & 8 here?

why this code not run in MATLAB2021a
    %%-----------awgn channel------------%%
    received=awgn(modulation,noise,'measured');
    %%-----------Rician channel------------%%
%     bitrate=5000000;
    bitrate=2.e-07;
    chan =comm.RicianChannel(bitrate,100,8);
    chan.ResetBeforeFiltering=0;
    fad=abs(filter(chan,ones(size(modulation))));
    fadedsignal=fad.*modulation;
    signal=awgn(fadedsignal,noise,'measured');
    received1=signal;

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.